# SQL Server Management Studio - Why is Dark Theme Disabled by Default?

Tags: ssms

Why is the Dark theme disabled by default?  Are there some bugs with this theme or something along those lines?  It seems odd to me that it is forcibly disabled on purpose.

I found plenty of links that I made use of to turn on the 'Dark' Theme for SSMS however I'm curious to know why this setting is turned off by default.  Why is this one single line commented out in the `ssms.pkgundef` file?

Here's one of many links that show how to make available the disabled Dark Theme.
[How to Enable Dark Them in SSMS](https://www.sqlshack.com/setting-up-the-dark-theme-in-sql-server-management-studio/)

Basically I'm curious if there is some sort of consequence I'm unaware of by turning this feature back on.  I can't find any links that state why it's turned off in the first place.

> Screenshot of Dark theme enabled after making changes to `ssms.pkgundef`

[image]

**To save this knowledge in the event of a dead link I have posted a screenshot below of how to edit the ssms.pkgundef file.**

**Note this has been tested in SSMS Version 19**

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19\Common7\IDE\ssms.pkgundef`

[image: Screenshot of editing the ssms.pkgundef file]

Comment: _Are there some bugs with this theme (...)?_ - Yes. See for instance https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/182949/78813

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it is a beta feature according to [this blog](https://datamajor.net/2018/11/08/sql-server-managment-studio-17-9-dark-theme/), and [this suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/33362758-dark-theme) as well as [this one for 18.1](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37920190-enabling-dark-theme-for-ssms-18-1).

As a workaround, you can get some custom themes from the web. A favorite of mine is [Aaron Bertrand's](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/making-ssms-pretty-my-dark-theme). He explains how to do it manually (so you can roll your own) and also provides a file you can just upload. [Other blogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dohollan/sql-server-2012-management-studio-darker-shades-of-blue-theme) mention this as well.

> Basically I'm curious if there is some sort of consequence I'm unaware
> of by turning this feature back on.

Like all BETA features, it isn't supported and thus if it breaks something else that's on you.